# mongo how to group a document by group field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

im having trouble to group a document. Frist i want to group by the 'field1' after that i want to make a new group with 'field2'. How its possible to do it? Look the example and thank u guys.

I'm using aggregate

my document exemple:

```
{
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2,
    name: 'ABC'
},
{
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2,
    name: 'ABC'
},
{
    field1: 2,
    field2: 3,
    name: 'ABC'
}
```

expect result:

```
[
   {
      "field1":1,
      "data":[
         {
            "field2":2,
            "data":[
               {
                  "name":"ABC"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ABC"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "field1":2,
      "data":[
         {
            "field2":3,
            "data":{
               "name":"ABC"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid JSON. Please correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_bX8e99dqFA)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "field1": "$field1", "field2": "$field2" },
    "data": { "$push": { "name": "$name" }}
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.field1",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "field2": "$_id.field2",
        "data": "$data"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 0, "data": 1, "field1": "$_id" }}
])
```

Comment: wow Thank u man. Your anwser was helpful, almost perfect. But in second $group in $push i change the "field1": "$field1" to  "field2" : "$_id.field2". And works great!! thank you. Should u edit your anwser for me check to resolve?